# Cosmos DB SQL shaping the output

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How can I use SQL for Cosmos DB to reshape this structure when querying?

Structure in the database:

```
{
   "id": "id-1",
   "Costs": {
            "Items": {
                "d1": {
                    "Title": "A1",
                    "Amount": 100
                },
                "d2": {
                    "Title": "A2",
                    "Amount": 200
                },
                "d3": {
                    "Title": "A3",
                    "Amount": 300
                }
   }
}
```

Output-structure:

```
{
  "id": "id-1",
  "Costs": {
                "d1": 100,
                "d2": 200,
                "d3": 300
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit to show what you’ve tried, and issue(s) you’re having; right now this is just a requirement.

Comment: Also: you should revisit your schema. You’re using data values as your property keys (which is an anti-pattern), along with not using an array for a variable number of like-kind sub-items, which means you have to request each individual item by name. This is not an ideal way to store your data, and is likely why you’re having difficulty querying it.

Comment: @DavidMakogon The "anti-pattern" is for storing a Dictionary<string,Value> (C#). It works like charm, especially for fast lookup and also when patching the document. I want to simplify the dictionary in the output, and I haven't tried any strategy yet, because I don't know how.

Comment: This pattern certainly causes problems if you ever want to enable the analytical store. This supports 1,000 unique property paths. If you are naming properties after values in the data then it is possible to exceed this very quickly. Whereas if `Items` was just an array of objects and each object has properties for `name, Title, Amount` this is just 3 paths not an unbounded amount

Comment: @MartinSmith That is good information to consider. Is that per item (document), or for the whole container?

Comment: For the whole container. It infers the schema based on property paths seen and stops collecting after 1,000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using UDF:

```
function reshapeItems(items) {
    var result = {};
    for (var key in items) {
        if (items.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            result[key] = items[key].Amount;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The SQL will be like this:

```
SELECT 
    c.id,
    UDF.reshapItems(c.Costs.Items) AS Costs
FROM c
WHERE c.id = "id-1"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Cosmos DB SQL shaping the output:**

Below are the steps I followed:

- `"d1": c.Costs.Items.d1.Amount` Pulls the **Amount** field from the **d1** sub-object within the **Items** object within the **Costs** object. This value is assigned to the new object's **d1** key.
- `"d2": c.Costs.Items.d2.Amount` and `"d3": c.Costs.Items.d3.Amount` Work in the same way as the **d1** extraction, except for the **d2** and **d3** sub-objects.
- `AS Costs` This renames the newly formed object to **Costs** in the output.
- The output object will have the key **Costs** including the "d1," "d2," and "d3" entries.

**Below Is the query I tried with:**

```
SELECT c.id,
{
    "d1": c.Costs.Items.d1.Amount,
    "d2": c.Costs.Items.d2.Amount,
    "d3": c.Costs.Items.d3.Amount
} AS Costs FROM c 

WHERE c.id = "id-1"
```

**Output:**

```js
[
    {
        "id": "id-1",
        "Costs": {
            "d1": 100,
            "d2": 200,
            "d3": 300
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: That is a good start yes. This solution require though that we know all the keys. I am looking for a solution that can do it without hardcoding the values d1, d2, d3, ...

Comment: @MaxP - you've shown no work of your own - this answer shouldn't have even been posted (there's no programming question yet). But I already explained to you how you hardcoded your data into keys - there's no simple workaround for that, aside from fixing your data model.

Comment: @DavidMakogon The way I do it today is that I take the whole structure to the client side and reshape it using C#. But I think the C# syntax is not relevant as the question is about Cosmos DB. I am trying to learn if there is a good way of doing it using Cosmos DB SQL on the server, because of curiosity.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I have added a possible solution.